# Combining CSV files into 1 CSV

Tags: python, csv

I am combining multiple CSV's in a folder into one CSV and for some reason when I run the code it keeps copying the same files into the 1 and repeating itself. Sorry if that is vague. Here's the code that I am running, this will probably explain it better than I did.

```
import csv
import glob

fo = open("CombinedLog.csv", "ab")

list = glob.glob('*.csv')
print list

for file in list:
  ifile  = open(file, "rb")
  reader = csv.reader(ifile)
  for row in reader:
    row = ",".join(row) + "\n"
    fo.write(row)
ifile.close()

fo.close()
```

Comment: Ugh. Why would you use a CSV reader to parse the CSV nicely, then write it back using `','.join` and lose all the escaping?

Comment: You're doing `open()` before you glob for `*.csv`. That means the globbed list will also contain your `CombinedLog.csv` because that one is created when you call `open()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is all you are doing, and you don't want a whole program for it... In windows command prompt from that directory, you can just run:

```
copy *.csv all.csv
```

This uses the wildcard * to copy all CSVs and creates a new file called "all.csv" that contains all of the data.

Edit:
If you want inside of python:

```
import os
os.system('copy *.csv all.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You opened the `CombinedLog.csv` for *appending*; every time you run this script more data will be added to the end, and the old data already there is retained.

Your code is working fine otherwise, but I'd use `csv.writer()` to format the output rows instead of using `','.join()`; you can feed the `csv.reader()` object *directly* into the `csv.writer()` `.writerows()` method and be done with it.

I'd also use the file objects as context managers with the `with` statement and have them closed automatically:

```
import csv
import glob

with open("CombinedLog.csv", "wb") as fo:
    fo_writer = csv.writer()

    csv_files = glob.glob('*.csv')
    for filename in csv_files:
    with open(file, "rb") as ifile:
        reader = csv.reader(ifile)
        fo_writer.writerows(reader)
```

Comment: I am getting the "with open" syntax error. I am running python 2.5.1 and from what I found online this should work though?

Comment: Add `from __future__ import with_statement` to the top of your module.

Comment: I'll be honest, I am a beginner with Python and have little programming experience so I am not sure how to add that?

Comment: Just add that one line at the start of the `.py` file.